# edit uploaded form using jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have one index.jsp page. In this page, user will fill some fields like zid, firstname, lastname and so on. While filling fields user selects file(s) to upload into MySQL database then click on "Submit" then file will be stored with details. Stored record are shown into filelist.jsp page. I have created one folder as "allfiles" where all user uploaded files will be stored and it is executed successfully. I also have one filelist.jsp page, where I have used this sql query to fetch all records from database **select * from dmsfiles**. All records are fetched in table form(column and rows). In this filelist.jsp page, I have one "Edit Form" column to edit form(index.jsp). If user wants to edit any file then he/she clicks on "Edit" then index.jsp will open then user do some changes as per need then click on update. Now the issue is when I click on "Edit" for any record then multiple forms(index.jsp) are opening one by other. I came to know that why it is happening but I am not getting solution. It is happening because, if suppose user **zid=1234** stored 4 files then **4 records** are showing into filelist.jsp **with same zid**. When I click on any "Edit" then 4 forms(index.jsp) are opening. What I want is that, When I click on any "Edit" then only that respective form(index.jsp) should open.

I have tried below editnew.jsp

```html
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Timestamp"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Document Management System</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide() {
   var checkbox = document.getElementById("chk");
   var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

    for (var i = 0; i != hiddeninputs.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
           hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "block";
        } 
        else {
          hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<div id="Registercontainer">
<div class="RegForm">
<div id="back_glob">
<div id="back_form">
<%
try{
      String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms";
      Statement stat = null;
      ResultSet res = null;
      Connection conn = null;
      PreparedStatement stmt = null;
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,"root","");
 %>
<form action="UploadServletClass" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<%
stat = conn.createStatement();
String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
String data = "select * from dmsfiles where zid = '"+zid+"'";
res = stat.executeQuery(data);
while(res.next()){
%>
<center>
<h2>Upload a New Document</h2>
</center>
<table width="400px" align="center" border="2">
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">Form Details</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Z id</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="zid" value='<%=res.getString(1)%>' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value='<%=res.getString(2)%>' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="lastname" value='<%=res.getString(3)%>' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mail id</td>
<td>
<input type="email" required="" name="mailid" value='<%=res.getString(4)%>' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Division</td>
<td>

......

<tr>
<td>Select File</td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="fileName" multiple="multiple" />
<span> <%=res.getString("filename")%> </span>
</td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>
<center><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<%
String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");
String de_pt = request.getParameter("department");
String cost_centercode = request.getParameter("costcentercode");
String doc_num = request.getParameter("documentnumber");     String doc_Name = request.getParameter("documentname");
String doc_Type = request.getParameter("Document_Type");   String doc_Category = request.getParameter("Document_Category");
String doc_classification = request.getParameter("Document_Classification");
String authorised_by = request.getParameter("authorisedby");
String from_date = request.getParameter("fromdate");
String to_date = request.getParameter("todate");
String document_level = request.getParameter("documentlevel");
String document_general = request.getParameter("documentgeneral");
String serial_number = request.getParameter("serialnumber");
String revision_number = request.getParameter("revisionnumber");
String iss_uer = request.getParameter("issuer");
String sta_tus = request.getParameter("status");
String file_Name = "";
String folder_Name = "allfiles";
String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            
if(z_id != null && first_Name != null && last_Name != null && mail_i_d != null && d_iv != null && de_pt != null && cost_centercode != null && doc_num != null && doc_Name != null && doc_Type != null && doc_Category != null && doc_classification != null && authorised_by != null && from_date != null && to_date != null && document_level != null && document_general != null && serial_number != null && revision_number != null && iss_uer != null && sta_tus != null && file_Name != null && folder_Name != null && pa_th != null && add_ed_date != null){

                String query = "update dmsfiles set zid=?,firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where zid='"+z_id+"'";
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                
                stmt.setString(1,z_id);
                stmt.setString(2,first_Name);
                stmt.setString(3,last_Name);
                stmt.setString(4,mail_i_d);
                stmt.setString(5,d_iv);
                stmt.setString(6,de_pt);
                stmt.setString(7,cost_centercode);
                stmt.setString(8,doc_num);
                stmt.setString(9,doc_Name);
                stmt.setString(10,doc_Type);
                stmt.setString(11,doc_Category);
                stmt.setString(12,doc_classification);
                stmt.setString(13,authorised_by);
                stmt.setString(14,from_date);
                stmt.setString(15,to_date);
                stmt.setString(16,document_level);
                stmt.setString(17,document_general);
                stmt.setString(18,serial_number);
                stmt.setString(19,revision_number);
                stmt.setString(20,iss_uer);
                stmt.setString(21,sta_tus);
                stmt.setString(22,file_Name);
                
                stmt.setString(23,pa_th);
                stmt.setTimestamp(24, null);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                response.sendRedirect("filelist.jsp");
          }
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}   
%>
</body>
</html>
```

filelist.jsp page

```html
<th class="text-center">Edit File</th>
...
<td><a href='editnew.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString("zid")%>'>Edit</a>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207250/discussion-on-question-by-priya-dhanba-edit-uploaded-form-using-jsp).

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more details i.e : the problem which you are currently facing ?

Comment: @Swati, could you please check above code that I have updated.

Comment: you can pass both`zid` and `document name` whenever you click on edit button `'editnew.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString("zid")%>&document_name=<%=rs.getString("document_name")%>'` and then pass both `zid` and `document_name` to your select query so that only that file will be shown where edit is clicked.

Comment: @Swati I tried as you said, When I clicked on "Edit" then I got only "Submit" button and Home link in form(with border).

Comment: I tried this query   String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
            String docName = request.getParameter("documentname");
           // String data = "select * from dmsfiles where document_name = '"+documentname+"' AND document_number = '"+docnum+"'";
            String data = "select * from dmsfiles where zid = '"+zid+"' AND document_name = '"+docName+"'";
            res = stat.executeQuery(data);
            while(res.next()){

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207323/discussion-between-swati-and-priya-dhanba).

Comment: I did <td><a href="editnew.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString("zid")%>&document_name=<%=rs.getString(9)%>">Edit</a></td>

Comment: @Swati did you checked uploadservletclass? :)

Comment: @Swati please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass file-path also as a query param to **editnew.jsp** and check